# get the hostname(Base URL) using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I get too many ways to get the hostname like code below:

```
window.location.host // you'll get sub.domain.com:8080 or sub.domain.com:80
window.location.hostname // you'll get sub.domain.com
window.location.protocol // you'll get http:
window.location.port // you'll get 8080 or 80
window.location.pathname // you'll get /virtualPath
```

In my case I want something different. For example:

My QA site name is `example.com/testsite/index.html`

My PROD site name is `example.com/index.html`

The problem here using the above methods to get the hostname it is returning me only the hostname like this: `example.com`

However for QA I need to return `example.com/testsite`

For PROD i need to return `example.com`

Is it possible with the single code? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You already have all the information you need... `window.location.hostname + window.location.pathname` I don't understand what is the problem :/

Comment: thanks for your comment,
but i dont know whether i am on QA or PROD at code side. to manupulate the actual path

Comment: The title of your question does not represent the problem you are facing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To achieve what you require you'll need to check the `window.location.hostname`, and also the first folder in the `window.location.pathname`. Something like this:

```
function getPath() {
  var folder = (window.location.pathname.split('/')[0] || '').toLowerCase() == 'testsite' ? '/testsite' : '';
  return window.location.hostname + folder;
}
```

Comment: thanks @Rory for reply, but there is not a fix name  like 'testsite' for folder under my site

Comment: Your question says there is...?

Comment: Ok, but then just change the string to whatever it should be. The logic is the same

Answer (score 2):

Best method that works for both PROD & QA

```
var BASE_URL = window.location.href;
    BASE_URL = BASE_URL.split("testsite");
    if (BASE_URL.length > 1)
    {
        BASE_URL = BASE_URL[0];
        BASE_URL = BASE_URL + 'testsite';
    } else{
        BASE_URL = window.location.origin;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **window.location.hostname;**

**Example:**
Page URL is  http://localhost:2239/Default2.aspx?id=5&name=SatinderSingh

```
var getCurrentURL =window.location.href; //http://localhost:2239/Default2.aspx?id=5&name=SatinderSingh
var getHostname=window.location.hostname; //localhost
var getPathName=window.location.pathname  // Default2.aspx
var getPortNo=window.location.port        // 2239
var getQueryString=window.location.search //?id=5&name=SatinderSingh
```

---

```
   var getHostname = window.location.hostname; //localhost
   var getPathName = window.location.pathname  // Default2.aspx
   var split_PathName = String(getPathName.split("/"));        
   var FinalURL = getHostname + "/" + split_PathName[1]
```

Comment: But what about getting the `/testsite` path in the response?

Comment: thanks @Satinder  for Your Response, but if   for QA  '(localhost/testsite/test/form.html)'    in this case it will work.  but PROD '(localhost/test/form.html)' it will give wrong finalurl